# Join query in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Hello I am new in **Cakephp** and I am having a hard time converting mysql queries in cakephp.I have this query which I want to convert into Cakephp syntax

```
SELECT * 
FROM trip
JOIN countries ON trip.departure_country_id = countries.id
WHERE countries.country_name LIKE  "eng%"
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
class Trip extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'trip';
    public $primaryKey = 'trip_id';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'fields' => array('User.user_id','User.first_name','User.last_name','User.profile_image','User.country','User.phone_no')

        ),
        'departure_country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'foreignKey' => 'departure_country_id',
        ),
        'arrival_country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'foreignKey' => 'arrival_country_id',
        )
    );

    public function getLocationBasedTrips($country){
        return  $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' => array('Country.country_name Like' => '%'.$country.'%')
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [ContainableBehavior documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved some brackets around from the previous answer. Try this:

```
 $this->find('all', array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'countries',
                    'alias' => 'Country',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Trip.departure_country_id = Country.id'
                    )
                )
            ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Country.country_name LIKE' => "%$country%"
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer. It is not giving me any error but it is also not printing any results.. like the result is coming empty...

Comment: debug the sql query using this `$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default'); 
debug($db->getLog());` and see if the sql query matches what you expect

Comment: okay I am confused here. I have debug it and then runs the query in phpmyadmin and it is showing the results correctly but why I am getting null in a variable...

Comment: oh sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Trip Model:

```
$this->find('all',
    array(
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'countries',
                'alias' => 'Country',
                'type' => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Trip.departure_country_id = Country.id'
                )
          ),
          'conditions' => array(
               'Country.country_name Like' => "%$country%"
          )
      )
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. This is the error I am getting 

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array WHERE 1 = 1' at line 1

Comment: I think it's a quote problem, I'm updating my answer.